# App Services Docker container: didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start

Tags: django, azure, docker

I'm having problems with deploying my Django Application to Azure App-services. I'm getting the error when checking the logs:

> didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See
> container logs for debugging.

I've followed the instructions as stated here to resolve the problem, but still no luck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#NoPing

**This is my set-up**

I have this in my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 80  
EXPOSE 8000
```

This is my dockercompose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python projectile/manage.py makemigrations && python projectile/manage.py migrate && python projectile/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: image_service
    volumes:
      - .:/image_service
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "8000"
```

I have these settings in the App Service Config in the portal

```
WEBSITES_PORT 8000
PORT 80
```

What's wrong here? Would be awesome if someone could help. me out.

Comment: did you build it in your local environment ?

Comment: What code is actually producing that error message?  If it's outside the container, are you looking up the `docker-compose port` of the HTTP service; or do you need to repeat the `ports:` number, `8000:8000`?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to Build your container in App Service., this is unsupported.  Deploy your image in a registry like Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry.

> Unsupported options
>
> - build (not allowed)
> - depends_on (ignored)
> - networks (ignored)
> - secrets (ignored)
> - ports other than 80 and 8080 (ignored)

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options)